# How do I update a collection item property that has no bound control in the xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a collection of items, say:

```cs
 class Myclass : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public bool Selected { get; set; }
     public string ChosenValue { get; set; }
 }
```

I then have an observable collection of this class:

```cs
 public ObservableCollection<Myclass> _myObColl
```

Finally I have a list box that is bound to `_myObColl` and a separate combobox that is bound to another collection.

I want updating the combobox to update the ChosenValue  property of all the items in `_myObColl` list. But I can't figure out how.

The combo box selected item is bound to a property in the viewmodel called currselection. What I want to do is bind the ChosenValue property of Myclass to the currselection value. But how do I do this? Maybe I shouldn't be thinking of binding but I can't think of another way to update the items ChosenValue property. I tried the `SelectionChanged` event of the combo to loop through `_myObColl`. This works except if an item is marked selected after the combobox is changed.

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.lstComboList , ElementName=PS4}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=currselection, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="100"/>
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding _myObColl}" Margin="10,10,0,0" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate x:Uid="asdasd"  >
                <DataTemplate>
                     <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>         
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column ="3" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=PropA, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the combo box to change the value of the selected item in the listbox you could bind the the SelectedItem like this.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.ChosenValue}" />
```

Otherwise if you really want to change the property of all the items in the list when the combo box changes you  would need to do it in code behind, in the property setter.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
```

In ViewModel

```
private string _SelectedValue;
public string SelectedValue
{
    get => _SelectedValue;
    set
    {
        _SelectedValue = value;
        foreach (var item in MyObColl.ToList()) item.ChosenValue = _SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @neilB I thought I could accomplish this through biding but I can make the SelectedValue set property work for me.